# Kafka property max.partition.fetch.bytes returns incorrect data size

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a basic JAVA Kafka Consumer that is consuming from a topic that has 10 partitions and over 1 GB of messages. Each message is around 250 KB.

`properties.setProperty("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "100000");`

Here is my understanding of how this property works. Please note: I have left all other properties to default values. The broker does accept messages up to 1 MB in size

This property, as per the settings above, will fetch up to 100 KB from each partition. The property does allow initially to pick messages larger than the set size as per the documentation. So, in this case it should pick 10 messages (one from each partition), which equals to 10 x 250 KB = 2.5 MB approx.

However, if I set the property to 200 KB, I should see the same response size. The real confusion starts when I set the property to 300 KB (larger than a single message size). Should I  now receive 2 messages/partition (500 KB/per partition) or it should still return a single message (250 KB) and discard the other message since it crosses the threshold of the set property? I get over 20 "MB" of data instead, which doesn't make any sense.

Or, am I missing any other property in addition to the max.partition.fetch.bytes property to make this work. Is it even the right syntax for providing the size to the property?

I am using Kafka 2.0.0 client API

Comment: What happens exactly also depends on which brokers the partitions are as fetches are made per broker. So can you clarify the broker/partition assignment?

Comment: Good point. I have 3 brokers in a cluster.

Comment: However, I tried with a single broker as well and the results are all skewed up.